# Bounds on the entropy of the 2D Ising model

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, ising-model

I am interested in good estimators of (or analytical bounds on) the entropy $\mathsf{H}_\beta:=-\sum_{\mathbf{x}} P(\mathbf{x})\log_2(P(\mathbf{x}))$ of the two-dimensional Ising model (with no external field) on configurations $\mathbf{x}$ on the 2D grid $\mathbb{Z}^2\cap [0,m]\times [0,n]$. The Hamiltonian is given by:
$$E(\mathbf{x}) = -\beta\sum_{i\sim j} J_{ij}x_i x_j,$$
where $i \sim j$ denotes that the  vertex $i$ is a neighbour of vertex $j$ in the grid.

What is known about bounds on the entropy? In particular, I am interested in causal distributions on configurations, which allow me to lower bound $\mathsf{H}_\beta$ (where, by causal, I mean that each of the conditional distributions $P_i$ in $P(\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^{mn} P_i(x_i|x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1})$ must be easily computable). Any simplifications such as setting $J_{ij} = J, \forall i,j$, such that $i\sim j$, are also acceptable.

My interest stems from wanting to compute information-theoretic quantities like the mutual information rate when one passes a 2D Ising model through a discrete memoryless channel ...